# Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown. Only on CAML Query

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, vb.net-2010

I am working with sharepoint webservice. If I call the GetListItems method with "Query" parameter as null. It works. But if I provide a Caml query as parameter its getting an exception like "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Is the "queryoption" parameter is mandatory while providing the parameter "query"?

Comment: No, it's not mandatory. I realize this question is over a year old, but what was your CAML query? In the future, you can try using [this tool](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) to test things.